# How to get 2 UserControls synchronized or access with Buttons / Code Behind instances in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I am having a problem in my project. This is my Solution Explorer:

[image]

BLA is an example UserControl that is loaded twice into a MainWindow Grid:

```
<Window x:Class="UserControlWechseln.MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControlWechseln"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="428" Width="1195" xmlns:am="http://schemas.amcharts.com/charts/wpf/2009/xaml">
    <Grid Height="1000" Width="1000">            
        <Grid Height="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,31,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142">
            <local:BLA Margin="-3,-17,-270,17" />
        </Grid> 

        <Grid Height="500" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,6,31,0" Name="grid2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="402">
            <local:BLA />
        </Grid>    
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The XAML Code for the BLA UserControl looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlWechseln.BLA"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Name="Bla">
        <Button Content="House" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="64,237,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"  Click="ButtonClick" />
        <Button Content="Soccer" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="169,237,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="ButtonClick" />    
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the C# Code for the BLA UserControl looks like this:

```
public partial class BLA : UserControl {
        public BLA() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            Bla.Children.Clear();

            if (btn.Content.ToString() == "House") {
                Haus uc1 = new Haus();
                Bla.Children.Add(uc1);
            } else if (btn.Content.ToString() == "Soccer") {
                Fussball uc2 = new Fussball();
                Bla.Children.Add(uc2);                
            }
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        }

        private void button1_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        }
    }
}
```

The problem now is that you get this view:

[image]

Is it possible to trigger the Home Button once and the Img in displays on both UserControls "BLA"? They obviously are the same UserControl.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are different instances of your UserControl, they do not know that the other exists. You are going to need to create `Properties` and `Events`. I am sure there is probably a better way of it but here is something I threw together to demonstrate( I also renamed some of your classes because I do not have the same Namespaces that you have). Also you are clearing all of the controls out of your UserControl when you change your image.

**Edit** added complete example

**UserControl**

```
namespace WpfApplication1{

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Bla.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Bla : UserControl
    {
        public event RoutedEventHandler changeHaus
        {
            add { AddHandler(myEvents.changeHausEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(myEvents.changeHausEvent, value); }
        }

        public event RoutedEventHandler changeSoccer
        {
            add { AddHandler(myEvents.changeSoccerEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(myEvents.changeSoccerEvent, value); }
        }

        public Bla()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { 
            Button btn = sender as Button; 
            if (btn.Content.ToString() == "House")
            {
                SetHaus();
                RoutedEventArgs ea = new RoutedEventArgs(myEvents.changeHausEvent);
                RaiseEvent(ea);
            }
            else if (btn.Content.ToString() == "Soccer")
            {
                SetSoccer();
                RoutedEventArgs ea = new RoutedEventArgs(myEvents.changeSoccerEvent);
                RaiseEvent(ea);
            }
        } 

        public void SetHaus()
        {
            display.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        }

        public void SetSoccer()
        {
            display.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
    }
    public static class myEvents
    {
        public static  RoutedEvent changeHausEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("changeHaus",RoutingStrategy.Tunnel,typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(Bla));
        public static RoutedEvent changeSoccerEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("changeSoccer", RoutingStrategy.Tunnel, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(Bla));

    }
}
```

**UserControl Xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Bla"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Name="bla">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Name="display" Height="223" Grid.Row="0" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="House" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="64,25,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"  Click="ButtonClick" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Soccer" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="169,25,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="ButtonClick" />
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

**Main Window**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bla1_changeHaus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bla2.SetHaus();
        }

        private void bla1_changeSoccer(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bla2.SetSoccer();
        }

        private void bla2_changeHaus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bla1.SetHaus();
        }

        private void bla2_changeSoccer(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bla1.SetSoccer();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Grid>
        <my:Bla HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,12,0,0" x:Name="bla1" VerticalAlignment="Top" changeHaus="bla1_changeHaus" changeSoccer="bla1_changeSoccer" />
        <my:Bla HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="247,12,0,0" x:Name="bla2" VerticalAlignment="Top" changeHaus="bla2_changeHaus" changeSoccer="bla2_changeSoccer" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hey Mark,

thx a lot for your answer i know understand its a Problem with diffrent Instances. 

But i don't get what you are trying to do in the Main Method.

i get errors With "bla2.setSoccer" and "bla2.getSoccer"

can you maybee post your complete Code with XAML i dont care about the img. 

the best Greetings Christopher!

Comment: @user1447444 Sorry I did not get back to you sooner, I was flying today. Here is the code for a quick and dirty example. I changed your UserControl and added a Rectangle for a visual. Any questions let me know

Comment: Mark it works :) thx so much. Know i have to transform this example into our big projekt but i will manage it^^

Comment: @user1447444 Glad to be of help.